# Macros to change pgfkeys package options on the fly and define custom sets of options

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, pgfkeys, options, pgfopts

Consider the following code for a package :

```
% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2024/01/01 MyPackage]
\makeatletter

% Dependencies
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

% Package options
\pgfkeys{
    /mypackage/.cd,
    firstcolor/.store in = \mypackage@firstcolor,
    firstcolor = blue,
    secondcolor/.store in = \mypackage@secondcolor,
    secondcolor = red,
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

% Definition of `\setcolors` here

% Definition of `\resetcolors` here

% Definition of `\printcolors` here

% Definition of `\newcolortheme` here

% End
\makeatother
```

I would like to define the three following functions, with the following behaviour:

- `\setcolors`: change `firstcolor` and `secondcolor` at point of call for the rest of the document
- `\resetcolors`: forget all the changes made by setcolors back to the original options of the package
- `\printcolors`: by default use the current global `firstcolor` and `secondcolor`, but has an optional parameter to override the global values by local values
- `\newcolortheme`: offer the possibility to create a colortheme to give a special name to a pair of `firstcolor` and `secondcolor`

This would look like this on the user side:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[firstcolor = green, secondcolor = yellow]{mypackage}
\newcolortheme{mytheme}{firstcolor = brown, secondcolor = cyan}

\begin{document}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[secondcolor = blue]  % Will print green and blue
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\setcolors{secondcolor = black}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black
\printcolors[firstcolor = purple] % Will print purple and black
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black

\setcolors{firstcolor = red}
\printcolors                      % Will print red and black

\setcolors{firstcolor = orange, secondcolor = pink}
\printcolors                      % Will print orange and pink

\resetcolors
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[mytheme]             % Will print brown and cyan
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\setcolors{mytheme}
\printcolors                      % Will print brown and cyan      
\end{document}
```

I have no idea how to make that happen.

**QUESTION :** How to define `\setcolors`, `\resetcolors`, `\printcolors` and `\newcolortheme` to make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible method:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2024/01/01 MyPackage]

% Dependencies
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\pgfkeys{/mypackage/.is family}
\def\mypackage@set#1{\pgfkeys{/mypackage,#1}}

\mypackage@set{
  % storage
  first-color/.store in=\mypackage@firstcolor,
  second-color/.store in=\mypackage@secondcolor,
  % default value
  first-color=blue,
  second-color=red,
  mypackage@init/.style/.expanded={
    first-color=\mypackage@firstcolor,
    second-color=\mypackage@secondcolor
  }
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

\mypackage@set{
  mypackage@init/.style/.expanded={
    first-color=\mypackage@firstcolor,
    second-color=\mypackage@secondcolor
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\newcolortheme{mm}{\mypackage@set{#1/.style={#2}}}

\NewDocumentCommand\printcolors{O{}}{%
  \bgroup%
  \mypackage@set{#1}%
  \mypackage@firstcolor{} and \mypackage@secondcolor{}\par%
  \egroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand\setcolors{m}{\mypackage@set{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand\resetcolors{}{\mypackage@set{mypackage@init}}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[preview=true,varwidth=true]{standalone}

\usepackage[first-color=green, second-color=yellow]{mypackage}

\newcolortheme{my theme}{first-color=brown, second-color=cyan}
% \setcolors{my theme/.style={first-color=brown, second-color=cyan}}

\begin{document}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[second-color=blue]   % Will print green and blue
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\setcolors{second-color=black}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black
\printcolors[first-color=purple]  % Will print purple and black
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black

\setcolors{first-color=red}
\printcolors                      % Will print red and black

\setcolors{first-color=orange, second-color=pink}
\printcolors                      % Will print orange and pink

\resetcolors
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[my theme]            % Will print brown and cyan
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\setcolors{my theme}
\printcolors                      % Will print brown and cyan      
\end{document}
```

(Note: The `\setcolor` macro is like an alias of `\mypackage@set`)

## Result

[image]

Comment: That's wonderful! However could your clarify why the init style should appear before and after the `ProcessPgfPackageOptions`?

Comment: @Vincent Indeed, creating the `mypackage@init` style before the call to `\ProcessPgfPackageOptions` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows two methods achieving that without `\printcolors` needing any grouping (which might or might not be preferable).

Both these codes use packages of the `expkv` family (*disclaimer:* of which I'm the author). The first one uses `expkv-cs` at its core, which makes it rather simple writing code which doesn't need groups (as the key=value handler doesn't need any assignments, hence the `\printcolors` macro works purely by expansion and without assignments -- if one exempts the parsing for an optional argument from this assertion). The second simply resets the default values on each call (in a rather performant manner), and `\setcolors` just changes the macro used to set back to defaults.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{\@currname}[2024-01-24 adhoc test package]

\RequirePackage{expkv-cs,expkv-opt,expkv-def}

% define keys as used for the package (we don't need the keys defined here
% otherwise)
\ekvdefinekeys{\@currname}
  {
     store   firstcolor  = \my@firstcolor
    ,initial firstcolor =  blue
    ,store   secondcolor = \my@secondcolor
    ,initial secondcolor = red
  }
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{\@currname}

% parsing for an optional argument
\newcommand\printcolors[1][]{\@printcolors{#1}}
% assign default values ('o: ' means expand value once)
\ekvcSplit\@printcolors
  {
     o: firstcolor  = \my@firstcolor
    ,o: secondcolor = \my@secondcolor
  }
  {#1 and #2\par}
% just change the default values of the underlying ekvc-macro
\protected\def\setcolors{\ekvcChange\@printcolors}
% store the current values (package defaults), using \edef for expansion
\protected\edef\resetcolors
  {%
    \setcolors
      {%
        % control the expansion to only do a single step (most likely
        % unnecessary but we never know with arbitrary user input)
         firstcolor  = {\unexpanded\expandafter{\my@firstcolor}}
        ,secondcolor = {\unexpanded\expandafter{\my@secondcolor}}
      }%
  }
% just define '#1' to be considered additional key=value input '#2' using
% ekvcSecondaryKeys.
\protected\def\newcolortheme#1#2%
  {\ekvcSecondaryKeys\@printcolors{nmeta #1 = {#2}}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{\@currname}[2024-01-24 adhoc test package]

\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{my}
  {
     store   firstcolor  = \my@firstcolor
    ,initial firstcolor =  blue
    ,store   secondcolor = \my@secondcolor
    ,initial secondcolor = red
  }
\ekvsetdef\@setcolors@keys{my}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{my}

% common code used to save the current values of all keys that should be
% persistent.
% 'o: ' means expand the value once before passing it to the key's code.
\newcommand*\my@storecolours@keys
  {%
     o: firstcolor  = \my@firstcolor
    ,o: secondcolor = \my@secondcolor
  }

% \@resetcolors is used to store the package default values
% 'R: ' means expand the following macro once and use it as key=value input
\protected\ekvcompile\@resetcolors{my}{R: \my@storecolours@keys}
% \@setcolors is used to restore the currently valid colours on each call
\protected\def\resetcolors{\let\@setcolors\@resetcolors}
\resetcolors
\protected\def\setcolors#1%
  {%
    % bit of juggling to get the normal key=value parser, but also build a fast
    % list of finalised colours
    \begingroup
      \ekvset{my}{#1}%
      \ekvcompile\@setcolors{my}{R: \my@storecolours@keys}%
    % expansion trick to store the meaning of \@setcolors as valid inside this
    % group outside the group, without needing any global assignments
    \expanded{\endgroup
    \protected\edef\noexpand\@setcolors
      {\noexpand\unexpanded{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@setcolors}}}%
    }%
  }
% just treat the key '#1' as additional key=value input containing '#2' (rather
% straight forward)
\protected\def\newcolortheme#1#2{\ekvdefNoVal{my}{#1}{\ekvmorekv{#2}}}

\newcommand\printcolors[1][]
  {%
    % restore current default values
    \@setcolors
    % maybe set different values
    \@setcolors@keys{#1}%
    % use values
    \my@firstcolor\space and \my@secondcolor
    \par
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[firstcolor = green, secondcolor = yellow]{\jobname} % both work
% \usepackage[firstcolor = green, secondcolor = yellow]{\jobname2} % both work

\newcolortheme{mytheme}{firstcolor = brown, secondcolor = cyan}

\begin{document}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[secondcolor = blue]  % Will print green and blue
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\bigskip
\setcolors{secondcolor = black}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black
\printcolors[firstcolor = purple] % Will print purple and black
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black

\bigskip
\setcolors{firstcolor = red}
\printcolors                      % Will print red and black

\bigskip
\setcolors{firstcolor = orange, secondcolor = pink}
\printcolors                      % Will print orange and pink

\bigskip
\resetcolors
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[mytheme]             % Will print brown and cyan
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\bigskip
\setcolors{mytheme}
\printcolors                      % Will print brown and cyan      
\end{document}
```

Regardless whether you `\usepackage{\jobname}` or `\usepackage{\jobname2}` the result will look like this:

[image]