# Initial style definition before and after ProcessPgfPackageOptions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, package-writing, package-options, pgfopts

The following great post, provides the following answer to a question about managing package options: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707285/17200

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mypackage.sty}
% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2024/01/01 MyPackage]

% Dependencies
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\pgfkeys{/mypackage/.is family}
\def\mypackage@set#1{\pgfkeys{/mypackage,#1}}

\mypackage@set{
  % storage
  first-color/.store in=\mypackage@firstcolor,
  second-color/.store in=\mypackage@secondcolor,
  % default value
  first-color=blue,
  second-color=red,
  mypackage@init/.style/.expanded={ % HERE
    first-color=\mypackage@firstcolor,
    second-color=\mypackage@secondcolor
  }
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

\mypackage@set{
  mypackage@init/.style/.expanded={ % HERE
    first-color=\mypackage@firstcolor,
    second-color=\mypackage@secondcolor
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\newcolortheme{mm}{\mypackage@set{#1/.style={#2}}}

\NewDocumentCommand\printcolors{O{}}{%
  \bgroup%
  \mypackage@set{#1}%
  \mypackage@firstcolor{} and \mypackage@secondcolor{}\par%
  \egroup
}

\NewDocumentCommand\setcolors{m}{\mypackage@set{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand\resetcolors{}{\mypackage@set{mypackage@init}}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[preview=true,varwidth=true]{standalone}

\usepackage[first-color=green, second-color=yellow]{mypackage}

\newcolortheme{my theme}{first-color=brown, second-color=cyan}
% \setcolors{my theme/.style={first-color=brown, second-color=cyan}}

\begin{document}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[second-color=blue]   % Will print green and blue
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\setcolors{second-color=black}
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black
\printcolors[first-color=purple]  % Will print purple and black
\printcolors                      % Will print green and black

\setcolors{first-color=red}
\printcolors                      % Will print red and black

\setcolors{first-color=orange, second-color=pink}
\printcolors                      % Will print orange and pink

\resetcolors
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow
\printcolors[my theme]            % Will print brown and cyan
\printcolors                      % Will print green and yellow

\setcolors{my theme}
\printcolors                      % Will print brown and cyan      
\end{document}
```

**QUESTION:** I am wondering why the `mypackage@init` needs to appear before and after the `\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}` (at the location that I annotated `HERE`)?

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION:** What does the `expanded` in the `mypackage@init/.style/.expanded` means/accomplishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first place marked by `HERE` doesn't do anything, unless someone uses the key `mypackage@init` inside the package options (I guess that's not intended, though), only the second is strictly necessary to set the colours' default values.

The `.expanded`-handler of `pgfkeys` fully expands the value before passing it to the key path above, so the `.style`-handler doesn't see the macros `\mypackage@firstcolor` or `\mypackage@secondcolor`, but instead only what was stored inside them (so in the default case `blue` and `red`). This way, whenever `mypackage@init` is used the colours are reset to the ones which were in effect when the package was loaded. (If the `.expanded` was omitted the macros `\mypackage@firstcolor` and `\mypackage@secondcolor` would be set in terms of themselves so be `\def\mypackage@firstcolor{\mypackage@firstcolor}` and build up an endless loop whenever used).