# Mixing package options and family options?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, package-writing, package-options, pgfopts

The question I am asking here is a follow-up to the question [Macros to change pgfkeys package options on the fly and define custom sets of options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707273/17200).

I was used to specify package options using the following technique:

```
\pgfkeys{
    /mypackage/.cd,
    firstcolor/.store in = \mypackage@firstcolor,
    firstcolor = blue,
    secondcolor/.store in = \mypackage@secondcolor,
    secondcolor = red,
}
\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}
```

In the answer to the original question ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707285/17200)), the following approach is provided:

```
\pgfkeys{/mypackage/.is family}
\def\mypackage@set#1{\pgfkeys{/mypackage,#1}}

\mypackage@set{
  % storage
  first-color/.store in=\mypackage@firstcolor,
  second-color/.store in=\mypackage@secondcolor,
  % default value
  first-color=blue,
  second-color=red,
  mypackage@init/.style/.expanded={
    first-color=\mypackage@firstcolor,
    second-color=\mypackage@secondcolor
  }
}

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

\NewDocumentCommand\setcolors{m}{\mypackage@set{#1}}
```

which makes it possible/easy to change options to new values in a document so I can type:

```
\usepackage[firstcolor = blue]{mypackage}
```

at first, and

```
\setcolors{firstcolor = red}
```

later on. But I am wondering of how I would do it if I wanted to add a `zerothcolor` which could only be set initially and not later?

---

**QUESTION:** In other words, how to add a `zerothcolor` option so that `\usepackage[zerothcolor = green]{mypackage}` works but `\setcolors{zerothcolor = green} does not?`

*Note: This is of course an example for me to understand the general principle and to make it work in a real-world scenario more complicated than just setting up colors*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be trivial if you used LaTeX's built in mechanism for key=value options, because they can get a validity specifying the key is only to be used during package load time and not later on.

Something like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
% demo-pkg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{\@currname}[Demo]

\DeclareKeys[my]
  {
     first-color  .store = \mypackage@firstcolor
    ,second-color .store = \mypackage@secondcolor
    ,zeroth-color .store = \mypackage@zerothcolor
    ,zeroth-color .usage = load
  }

\ProcessKeyOptions[my]

\NewDocumentCommand\showvalues{}
  {%
    0th: \mypackage@zerothcolor,
    1st: \mypackage@firstcolor,
    2nd: \mypackage@secondcolor
    \par
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\setcolors{m}{\SetKeys[my]{#1}}
\end{filecontents}

% main.tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[zeroth-color=green]{\jobname}

\setcolors{first-color=red, second-color=blue, zeroth-color=yellow} % ERROR
\begin{document}
\showvalues
\end{document}
```

throws the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Key "zeroth-color" may only be used during loading of package
(LaTeX)        "my".
```

---

Using `pgfkeys` we can emulate this behaviour by redefining the key after the package options were processed:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.sty}
% demo-pkg.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{\@currname}[Demo]

\RequirePackage{pgfkeys,pgfopts}

\NewDocumentCommand\setcolors{m}{\pgfqkeys{/mypackage}{#1}}
\setcolors
  {
    .is family,
    % storage
    first-color/.store in  = \mypackage@firstcolor,
    second-color/.store in = \mypackage@secondcolor,
    zeroth-color/.store in = \mypackage@zerothcolor,
    % default value
    first-color=blue,
    second-color=red,
    mypackage@init/.style/.expanded={
      first-color=\mypackage@firstcolor,
      second-color=\mypackage@secondcolor
    }
  }

\ProcessPgfPackageOptions{/mypackage}

\setcolors
  {
    zeroth-color/.code = \PackageError{mypackage}
      {%
        Key "zeroth-color" may only be used during loading\MessageBreak
        of package "mypackage"%
      }%
      {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\showvalues{}
  {%
    0th: \mypackage@zerothcolor,
    1st: \mypackage@firstcolor,
    2nd: \mypackage@secondcolor
    \par
  }
\end{filecontents}

% main.tex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[zeroth-color=green]{\jobname}

\setcolors{first-color=red, second-color=blue, zeroth-color=yellow} % ERROR
\begin{document}
\showvalues
\end{document}
```

which throws the similar error:

```
! Package mypackage Error: Key "zeroth-color" may only be used during loading
(mypackage)                of package "mypackage".
```